# sum of Fibbonaci Sequences?

Tags: python

Trying to add the sum of Fibonacci, using definite loops. It's meant to calculate the summation of Fibonacci number with each number too. Below is the sample for the Fibonacci sequence and its summation, how do i add the sum of the fibonacci eg 1,1,2,3,5,8

Fibonacci       Summation

0                                  0

1                                  1

1                                  2

2                                  4

3                                  7

5                                  12

8                                  20

```
n = int(input("enter"))

def fibonacciSeries():
    a=0
    b=1
    
    for i in range (n-2):
        x = a+b
        a=b
        b=x
        int(x)
        x[i]= x+x[i-1]
#should add the previous sequences

        
        print(x)
      
        
fibonacciSeries()
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep track of the whole sequence. Plus your Fibonacci implementation doesn't start with 1, 1 but rather 1, 2 so I fixed that.

```
def fibonacciSeries(n):
    a=0
    b=1
    x=1
    series_sum = 0
    for i in range (n-2):
        series_sum += x
        print(f'{x} {series_sum}')
        x = a+b
        a=b
        b=x
        
n = 10
fibonacciSeries(n)
```

Output:

```
1 1
1 2
2 4
3 7
5 12
8 20
13 33
21 54
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacciSeries(n):
    sum = 0
    a = 0
    b = 1
    x = 1
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,n - 2):
        sum += x
        print(x,sum)
        x = a + b
        a = b
        b = x
n = int(input("enter : ")) # n = 8
fibonacciSeries(n)
```

Output:

```
enter : 8
1 1
1 2
2 4
3 7
5 12
8 20
```